# Extracting date from a string without pattern

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I've recently started working on a excel sheet that is dependent on a string of description posted on the oracle database.

The string goes something like this

> 1 year Rent Charges for Parking for the Period of 18-8-1438 to 17-8-1439 / 15-5-17 to 4-5-18
>
> 6 months rent charges for Street from 01-08-1438 to 01-02-1439 / 28-04-2017 to 21-10-2017
>
> 1Year rent charges for 310113- Outlet for the period of 01-01-1438 to 30-12-1438

and any other form that the person posting the description feels comfortable with.

Now my question is how do I extract the dates from these description easily through excel function or a vba macro. Bonus would be to able convert hijri dates to Gregorian on the fly rather than having to convert those through a web service.

Edit: Forgot to mention the desired output (thanks Mate Juhasz), the output needs to be something that can be used in the days360 formula such as mm/dd/yyyy. There will mostly be 2 dates in each entry, contract start date and contract end date, with the possibility of the same being posted along with hijri and rarely only hijri date. Always check for dd/mm/yyyy or dd/mm/yy as that's their usual posting format.

Comment: Please also specify your desired output. (e.g. are 14xx valid years for you? what dates do you consider valid from first input? Do you have 2 dates in each entry, or can it be multiple?) Do you want to always check dd/mm/yyyy, or want to check mm/dd/yyyy in case the previous one would fail? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. extract dates

I use [RegEx Find/Replace](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php) add-in such cases, which adds regular expression functionality to Excel.

You can use it also as an array formula:

- as you expect max four dates per cell, select four cells in a row (e.g. B3:E3 in the example)
- type formula:
  `=RegExFind(A3,"\d+-\d+-\d+")`
- press CTRL+Shift+Enter
- copy formula down

This will look for all dates entered as 1/2 digit day/month and 2/4 digit year, parts are separated by a single `-`

### 2. convert extracted texts to dates

In the examples I've used `DATEVALUE` functions, which works for Gregorian calendar only, I don't have experience with hijri.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this worked nicely in extracting the dates. I'm getting #value error on using datevalue function on the extracted dates, any possible reasons for this?

Comment: [`DATEVALUE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEVALUE-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252) uses regional settings to convert date, you may need to change them.

Comment: That worked. Your help was invaluable in standardizing my work, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using VBA without Regex:

```
Sub GetDateCandidates()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, s As String
    Dim K As Long, a, bry

    K = 2
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
        s = Cells(i, 1).Value
        ary = Split(s, " ")
        For Each a In ary
            bry = Split(a, "-")
            If UBound(bry) = 2 Then
                If (TestBry(bry)) Then
                    Cells(i, K).Value = "'" & a
                    K = K + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next a
        K = 2
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function TestBry(b) As Boolean

    TestBry = False

    If Not IsNumeric(b(0)) Then Exit Function
    If Not IsNumeric(b(1)) Then Exit Function
    If Not IsNumeric(b(2)) Then Exit Function
    If Len(b(0)) > 2 Then Exit Function
    If Len(b(1)) > 2 Then Exit Function
    If Len(b(2)) = 2 Or Len(b(2)) = 4 Then TestBry = True
End Function
```

The phrases are in column **A**.  Each phrase is separated into words using spaces as the separator.  Each word is separated into items using the *dash* as a separator.  If:

1. there are three items
2. all three items are numeric
3. the length of the first two items is either *1* or *2*
4. the length of the third item is either *2* or *4*

The word is stored next to the phrase:

[image]

Comment: How do I invoke this command to fetch dates from the column?

Answer (score 0):

In the examples you gave, it does follow a pattern.

The pattern is: At least one digit, followed by a symbol that's either a dash or a slash. (x2) and ending in either 2 or 4 digits. And they're all in the same line.

So you could use regex to return all results matching such a pattern. My regex is a bit rusty, but the pattern would be something like:

```
\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{2,4}
```

This would match for example a DD/MM/YYYY format as well as a D-M-YY format, and permutations thereof.

If you want to parse the **from / to** date format, you might use this search string:

```
\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{2,4}\s*to\s*\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{1,2}[\/-]\d{2,4}
```

Of course, you'd need to run it through a regex engine and harvest the output.

Then you might want to standardize said output so it all matches a **DD/MM/YYYY** format - although I have to say I prefer **YYYY-MM-DD** given how computers index things for searches. You can do this with regex too, by grouping numbers and reorganizing them with search and replace. Let me know if that sounds like something you'd be keen to try.

Finally then, you might want to convert the standardized output to the gregorian calendar. Which you might do by having an excel formula run a calculation if the value for the year is lower than say 1900 or something.

Best of luck. Standardizing data like this can be a nightmare, although scripts and regex help tremendously.

Comment: I'd like to try this out. Let me know what are the next step involved in the process.

Comment: @Herubrand Sorry for not replying sooner. Didn't realize anyone had inquired about it.   iirc the way to do this is:

If you have 12/04/2017 which is typical american. you could do a search & replace, where you search for the pattern: `(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2,4})`  and replace it with the pattern `\3-\1-\2`  then just do a find & replace all.

Finally, if the years are all after 2000 for example, and they only use a 2 digit year formula, you could then do a lookup for `(\d\d)[\s|$]` and replace it with `\/20\1` This should work i think.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your own RegEx function to simplify:

```
    Function RegEx(Target As String, RegExpression As String, _
                   Optional ReplaceString As String, Optional xIgnoreCase As Boolean, _
                   Optional xGlobal As Boolean, Optional xMultiLine As Boolean)
    
        Dim regexOne As Object
                
        Set regexOne = New RegExp
        regexOne.Pattern = RegExpression
        If xIgnoreCase Then regexOne.IgnoreCase = xIgnoreCase
        If xGlobal Then regexOne.Global = xGlobal
        If xMultiLine Then regexOne.MultiLine = xMultiLine
        
        If regexOne.Test(Target) Then
            If IsMissing(ReplaceString) Then
                RegEx = regexOne.Execute(Target)
            Else
                RegEx = regexOne.Replace(Target, ReplaceString)
            End If
        End If
            
    End Function
```